# How can I stop VS Code persistently displaying its windows 32-bit deprecation warning banner?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am a Visual Studio Code user and I am using it on a 32-bit Windows device.
These days, I keep getting the warning message on the top:

> This is the last Windows 32-bit supported version of Visual Studio Code. Consider upgrading to the 64-bit build.

I completely understand what it means, but I still don't have any plan of upgrading my Windows version from 32-bit to 64-bit, just to get the newest Visual Studio Code. It's time wasting.

But, sometimes, the error message is just so annoying, because it pops up every time I 'launch' Visual Studio Code.

I want to stop the message from displaying again.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the source code for the exact warning message text you gave, but I did find some similar ones:

- [For 1.82.3](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/fdb98833154679dbaa7af67a5a29fe19e55c2b73/src/vs/workbench/electron-sandbox/window.ts#L726)
- [For 1.83.1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/f1b07bd25dfad64b0167beb15359ae573aecd2cc/src/vs/workbench/electron-sandbox/window.ts#L726)

I don't see any obvious way to prevent this from popping up given the linked source code, which doesn't have any local conditionals upon any related settings.

I mean... I suppose you could try modifying your VS Code installation's workbench.js file, but that itself is a hassle because it's minified JS, and it'd just create another problem, because VS Code will issue a corruption warning upon startup when it detects that its installation files have been modified (though you can mark that warning to not be shown again).

Related:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_windows-32bit-support-ends
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_can-i-run-vs-code-on-older-windows-versions

Answer (score -2):

"update.mode": "none",
"update.showReleaseNotes": false,

Open Visual Studio Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings (or use the shortcut Ctrl + ,), and then click on the Open Settings (JSON) icon in the top-right corner. Add the above lines to the settings.json file.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is wrong (at least- I'd be surprised if it's right). let's see what the asker says when they try it.

Comment: Yes, actually, @starball is right, this didn't really solve my problem, as it still displays the message :(